# Docker compose: How to solve Address already in use

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup PHP+mySQL container for a legacy application. I used following Docker-compose.yml

```yaml
name: rideally-zf
services:
  zf-web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: zfweb.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - APPLICATION_ENV=local
    ports:
      - '8090:80'
    volumes:
      - ./rideallynewDesign:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - ra-mysql
    networks:
      custom_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.200.1
  ra-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7-debian
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rideallyroot
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=rideally_rideallyin
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=rideally
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysqlralocal:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    networks:
      custom_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.200.2
volumes:
  mysqlralocal:
networks:
  custom_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.200.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.200.1
```

zfweb.Dockerfile is simply setting ServerName as follow:

```
FROM php:5.6.40-apache

RUN echo "ServerName 192.168.200.1" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart
```

While trying to run `docker compose up --build`, I'm getting following erros:

```bash
PS C:\Users\kapil\dev\docker\RA-ZF> docker compose down --rmi all
[+] Running 5/5
 - Container rideally-zf-zf-web-1      Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 - Container rideally-zf-ra-mysql-1    Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 - Image rideally-zf-zf-web:latest     Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 - Image mysql:5.7-debian              Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.8s 
 - Network rideally-zf_custom_network  Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s 
PS C:\Users\kapil\dev\docker\RA-ZF> docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)    
14dcc9ec4ab1
314b1d09eea1
a388c643a3a7
11e1f378af9e
c31e64d5eb27
64c9ed6d9b18
0f1e28d9f789
8bb496ae4920
398abe872a8e
cbe7e3fc1b1f
1c5930d73610
8ebe7f359a40
0782188fa885
33b8cd078884
5a9e6bef532c
d94c188d18d0
1b2af074dfcb
e2b82377af74
PS C:\Users\kapil\dev\docker\RA-ZF> netstat -ano | findstr :3306      
PS C:\Users\kapil\dev\docker\RA-ZF> netstat -ano | findstr :3366  
PS C:\Users\kapil\dev\docker\RA-ZF> netstat -ano | findstr :80  
  UDP    [::]:52066             [2404:6800:4009:809::200a]:443                  4940
  UDP    [::]:54174             [2404:6800:4009:80e::200a]:443                  4940
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN echo "ServerName 192.168.200.1" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/3] RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:59424d3997e14f7a18ca5e7c6e997e3da7c8788cb372f8b5cec3aec246f6956f                                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/rideally-zf-zf-web                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 3/3
 - Network rideally-zf_custom_network  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.1s 
 - Container rideally-zf-ra-mysql-1    Created                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.5s 
 - Container rideally-zf-zf-web-1      Created                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s 
Attaching to rideally-zf-ra-mysql-1, rideally-zf-zf-web-1
rideally-zf-ra-mysql-1  | 2023-04-02 09:59:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.41-1debian10 started.
Error response from daemon: Address already in use
PS C:\Users\kapil\dev\docker\RA-ZF>
```

Could someone help me understand what address is in use and how to free that?

Comment: Try a different IP and see if you can fix the issue. Check with `ip a` or `ip -br -c a`. As the ports seem not to be used.

Comment: Thanks @Andromeda Changing ip to 192.168.200.10/20 fixed the issue. I couldn't understand why. Above IP were not in use as far as I understand.

Comment: I might guess that 192.168.200.1 is the gateway address, which will point back to the host machine, and so you can't assign it to a container.  But you don't need to manually assign IP addresses to containers at all; the container-private IP addresses are unreachable in most circumstances and Docker can assign the addresses just fine on its own.  If you delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file, does this resolve the problem?